# Delete all paired bluetooth devices on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I would like to delete paired bluetooth low energy devices with names that start with "ABC" on an Android phone programatically.

I am using Android studio.

Answer (score 2):

If you are specific about BLE(bluetooth low energy), 
To get all bonded devices you can write a method as.

```
public List<BluetoothDevice> getConnectedDevices() {
        BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        return btManager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothProfile.GATT);
    }
```

This return the list of BLE devices connected in GATT profile. 
    Fetch the name confirm if this the device you want to disconnet as:

```
List<BluetoothDevice> btdevices = getConnectedDevices();
                for(int i=0;i<btdevices.size();i++)
                {
                    //match your device here
                    Log.d("saurav"," BLE Name:"+btdevices.get(i).getName());
            }
```

To disconnect you can simply call disconnect method. You need disconnect with gatt instance(Same gatt instance you used to connect the BLE device).

```
public void disconnect() {
        if (gatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        gatt.disconnect();

    }
```

This will disconnect your BLE device. I have teste tshi personally and working for me.